# How to inspect the underlying network requests made by VSCode extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to use this extension: https://github.com/prisma/vscode-graphql and I am getting a weird unexpected network error.

`Error: Network error: When parsing the constructor GraphQLRequest of type Hasura.GraphQL.Transport.HTTP.Protocol.GraphQLRequest expected Object but got Array.`

I wish to look at the extension's underlying network request to find the root cause of the problem.

Note: I tried `Help -> Toggle developer tools`. The network request does not reflect there.

Comment: Any news on that? Did you manage to find a way to see the requests?

Comment: Where and _when_ does that error appear? When you're debugging an application? In the terminal? In an output channel in the Output view?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [`tcpdump`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump)